# Excel, qn regarding generating random marital status

Tags: excel, random, excel-formula

i have a qn regarding excel, does anyone here know how to randomly generate a character between "M","S" and "D" for each cell? Thanks you so much in advance

Answer (score 1):

Try below formula-

```
=INDEX({"M","S","D"},,RANDBETWEEN(1,3))
```

[image]